# How to intercept the back button on an Android Service?

Tags: android, xamarin, button, service, back

I'm displaying a layout over all the other apps with `ApplicationOverlay` and the `WindowManager`.

When I click the back button. The `OnBackPressed()` override of my activity doesn't fire because of the overlay.

How can I detect and cancel the back button from a Service on android so that when I press back I can make my application change its layout?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT I don't remember the exact solution I used for this issue, but I think it was when I set my view to have focus with `myView.RequestFocus(FocusSearchDirection.Forward);`

Answer (score 1):

If you have the overlay attached to the WindowsManager, you just need to add a listener to the view:

```
view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            stopSelf();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: That callback does not get triggered when I click the back button. It seems the back button is being completely eaten or ignored while this overlay is on.

Answer (score 0):

When you create `WindowManagerLayoutParams` add the below flags:

```
layoutParams.Flags = WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchModal;
layoutParams.Flags = WindowManagerFlags.NotFocusable;
```

then you could fire the `OnBackPressed()` method in your activity.